# Dependency problems when updating gcc-4.9-base (and similar) packages

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

I normally check for updates myself, just to be sure that I have the latest everything. When I went to check for updates again today, nothing appeared in the list! So I click <kbd>Install Now</kbd> anyway. Software Updater gives me the following error:

> ***Package dependencies cannot be resolved.***
>   This error could be caused by required additional software packages which are missing or not installable. Furthermore there could be a conflict between software packages which are not allowed to be installed at the same time.

I also got a red icon on my Ubuntu panel that displays this message:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what's wrong. The error message was: 'Error: Marking the upgrade (E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.)'. This usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

. So I opened Synaptic, and clicked <kbd>Mark All Upgrades</kbd>. It wants to get rid of at least a hundred different packages (plenty of which are critical for Ubuntu to work!) to install just a handful! When I mark them anyway, I get:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

W: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
W: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

I decided to click `Edit > Fix Broken Packages`, but upon doing so I get:

```
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Packages `gvfs-daemons` and `libstdc++6` are marked as broken, but I don't want to have to remove so many packages just to resolve dependencies. What should I do?!?

---

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Output of `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-daemons libstdc++6`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 660 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main gvfs-daemons amd64 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 [108 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin/ubuntu/ trusty/main libstdc++6 amd64 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 [269 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/gcc-for-dolphin/ubuntu/ trusty/main libstdc++6 i386 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 [283 kB]
Fetched 660 kB in 10s (60.1 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 1325331 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) over (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:i386 (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) over (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:amd64 (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Setting up libstdc++6:i386 (4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
(Reading database ... 1325331 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gvfs-daemons_1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gvfs-daemons (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) over (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up gvfs-daemons (1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2) ...
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Output of `apt-cache policy gvfs-daemons x11-utils libstdc++6 gcc-4.9-base`:

```
gvfs-daemons:
  Installed: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.20.3-0ubuntu1.2 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.20.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
x11-utils:
  Installed: 7.7+1
  Candidate: 7.7+1
  Version table:
 *** 7.7+1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/… trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
gcc-4.9-base:
  Installed: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.3-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     4.9.3-0ubuntu4 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/… trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.9.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'getdeb.list.bck' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

---

**UPDATE:** The problem has returned. As previously suggested, the `trusty-proposed` source is still unchecked, but the very same problem has now appeared in the main channel (`trusty-updates`). I need to resolve the dependencies, or else I will not be able to easily update everything. I have the information stored in the [Ubuntu Pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14492942/).

Comment: Run the command `sudo apt-get install -f` and press `n`. Add the output to tour question.

Comment: @A.B. Ran the command, but I didn't need to press `n`. Either I did it wrong, or there are *that* many unresolved dependencies!

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gvfs-daemons libstdc++6` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I can't see problem =\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32219/discussion-between-a-b-and-borwal).

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: @Daniel Didn't work. [Output of your command.](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14503923/)

Comment: Try `cp /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list ; mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list.bck ~/` and then try updating again.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the output of `apt-cache policy gvfs-daemons x11-utils libstdc++6 gcc-4.9-base`, the installation candidate for `gcc-4.9-base` is `4.9.3-0ubuntu4`:

```
gcc-4.9-base:
  Installed: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.3-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
     4.9.3-0ubuntu4 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/… trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.9.1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

This version is available in `trusty-proposed`.

**But** the problem is, `libstdc++6` has version `4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04` and there is no candidate with the version `4.9.3-0ubuntu4` to install and the versions of `libstdc++6` and `gcc-4.9-base` have to be exactly the same.

```
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04
  Version table:
 *** 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 ppa.launchpad.net/dolphin-emu/… trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
     4.8.2-19ubuntu1 0
        500 archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

For this reason, disable `trusty-proposed`:

```
sudo sed -i '/trusty-proposed/d' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and repair

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

**Update for the update in your question:**

Upgrade

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-base=4.9.3-0ubuntu4
```

Downgrade

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6=4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8-base
```

Comment: Yes, that's ok.

Comment: Doesn't work. I tried each command in the order that you put. The first one didn't work at all, the second *did* downgrade, but the third tells me it's already the newest version.

Comment: [This is what I am dealing with.](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14501210/) I've already auto-removed some packages, but it wants me to remove more. UGH!

Comment: I've got more new info from the command `apt-cache policy gvfs-daemons x11-utils libstdc++6 gcc-4.9-base` in the pastebin [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/14501332/).

Comment: @BorWal , force back `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6=4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04` as I see from your new output is still in `4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04` from the removed ppa. then try again

Comment: Never mind. I just did a fresh install of my entire system. Everything works, now.